# How is the dynamic program designed for this problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am working on this problem: [Maximum games played by winner](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-games-played-winner/)
. Quoted here for convenience:

There are N players which are playing a tournament. We need to find the maximum number of games the winner can play. In this tournament, two players are allowed to play against each other only if the difference between games played by them is not more than one.

**Input  :**
`N = 4`
**Output :** `2`

```
Maximum games winner can play = 2
Assume that player are P1, P2, P3 and P4
First two pairs will play lets (P1, P2) and 
(P3, P4). Now winner of these two games will 
play against each other, making total games
played by winner = 2
```

My confusion is with this below approach explained:

> We can solve this problem by first computing minimum number of players required such that the winner will play x games. Once this is computed actual problem is just inverse of this. Now assume that dp[i] denotes minimum number of players required so that winner plays i games. We can write a recursive relation among dp values as,
> dp[i + 1] = dp[i] + dp[i – 1] because if runner up has played (i – 1) games and winner has played i games and all players against which they have played the match are disjoint, total games played by winner will be addition of those two sets of players.
> Above recursive relation can be written as dp[i] = dp[i – 1] + dp[i – 2]

Here is my understanding.

```
Let's say 4 players p1, p2, p3, p4.

The games are
Game 1: (p1, p2) winner p1
Game 2: (p3, p4) winner as p3
Game 3: (p1,p3) winner as p1

The winner is p1 and the runner is p3.
```

At Game 1, Runner p3 has played 0 games. so dp[i-1] = 0. Winner has played 1 game so dp[i] = 1. so dp[2] = 1 + 0 = 1. I am totally confused how to understand this approach towards solution.

Finally the solution is this:

```
int maxGameByWinner(int N)
{
  int[] dp = new int[N];
          
  // for 0 games, 1 player is needed
  // for 1 game, 2 players are required
  dp[0] = 1;   
  dp[1] = 2;
              
  // loop until i-th Fibonacci number is 
  // less than or equal to N
  int i = 2;
  do {
    dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2];
  } while (dp[i++] <= N);
          
  // result is (i - 2) because i will be
  // incremented one extra in while loop
  // and we want the last value which is
  // smaller than N, so one more decrement
  return i - 2;
}
```

Also I am not clear what it means `// result is (i - 2) because i will be incremented one extra in while loop and we want the last value which is smaller than N, so one more decrement return (i - 2);`

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. What is wrong with `(p1, p2); (p1, p3); (p4, p2), (p1, p4)` (match winner listed first)?. Now `p1` with 3 points won the tournament after _3_ matches. There are unstated some assumptions on how the tournament is run.

Comment: @user58697 Here is my understanding. If someone lose a match, they can't participate in any other matches.

Answer (score 2):

### Clarification

Just as the comments point out, the problem is actually missing some requirements. However, from the suggested solution, we can guess that the missing requirement is that the loser of any match will get eliminated immediately and cannot participate in future matches.

### Idea

The number of winning matches between two players need to be smaller than or equal to 1. How to approach this? Let's start with `n=2` first

```
1   2
 \ /
  1 (winner)
```

It is obvious that the winner can win with at most 1 match. How about `n=3`?

```
1   2   3
 \ /   /
  1   /
   \ /
    1 (winner)
```

The winner can win with at most 2 matches in this case, now think about how to find minimal `n` such that the answer is `3`. In fact, we can just combine the above two trees!

```
1   2   3         Round 1
 \ /   / 
  1   /   4   5   Round 2
   \ /     \ /
    1       4     Round 3
     \     /
      \   /
       \ /
        1 (winner)
```

Observe how is the above tree a combination of the `n=2` and `n=3` cases. In Round 3, `1` has won two matches (as `n=2`) and `4` has won one match (as `n=1`) so the competition between them is legal. Therefore, it can be seen that to the minimal `n` such that answer is 4 is

```
(the minimal n such that the answer is 3) + (the minimal n such that the answer is 2)
```

This idea can be applied in the same way for larger `n`. This is where the `dp[n] = dp[n - 1] + dp[n - 2]` comes from.

### Implementation

Once you get the idea, you should be able to understand the c++ code. We get the `dp` array as follows: (where `dp[i]` means that the minimal `n` such that the answer is `i`)

```
dp[0] dp[1] dp[2] dp[3] dp[4]
1     2     3     5     8
```

What we want to do is just find i such that `dp[i] <= n < dp[i + 1]`. For example, for `n=2`, `i=1`; for `n=6`, `i=3`, etc

```
do {
   dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2];
} while (dp[i++] <= N);
```

The above code is one way to implement it, although it must not be the most readable code on earth. One could easily achieve the same purpose with two loops.

If you really want to understand why the answer is `i - 2`, here is a brief explanation. The above loop stops only when `n < dp[i++]`, which is equivalent to `n < dp[i]; i++` in c++. But in fact, what we want to find is an element in `dp` that is smaller than or equal to `n`, so the value is offset by 1. Also, `i++` results in another offset by 1. Therefore, `i - 2` would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

##### To understand the problem better, let's first list out the answer for small values of N. When there are N players, the maximum number of wins of the winners are as follow:

```
  N  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
ans  0  1  2  2  3  3  3  4  4
```

As you can see, for increasing value of N, the answer can only increase. We can now denote `dp[i]` as the minimum N such that `ans >= i`, i.e.
`dp[0]` will be the minimum N such that `ans >= 0`, which will be `N = 1`
`dp[1]` will be the minimum N such that `ans >= 1`, which will be `N = 2`
`dp[2]` will be the minimum N such that `ans >= 2`, which will be `N = 3`
`dp[3]` will be the minimum N such that `ans >= 3`, which will be `N = 5`

#### How to find `dp[i]` for any `i`.

As `dp[i]` denotes the minimum N (number of players) such that `ans` (number of wins of the winner) is at least `i`, we will need someone who has won `i - 1` match to win one more match. We can do that by matching the player who won `i - 1` match with someone who won `i - 2` match, this will require the minimum number of players for the winner to win `i` matches.
**Therefore, `dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]`**
We need `dp[0] = 1` and `dp[1] = 2` before calculating because we need 2 elements in `dp` array to apply the formula above.

#### Why we need `i - 2` in the end

Let's revisit the original question. Now that we have the dp array, how can we find the answer now?
The answer is now same as finding `i` such that `N >= dp[i]` and `N < dp[i + 1]`, we can see that there will only be one such `i` as N can only be between 2 element in the `dp` array. (refer to the table above)
After the do while loop, the last thing that got executed is `dp[i++] <= N` which will be **false** as we exited the loop.
Therefore, we have `dp[i - 1] > N` and `dp[i - 2] <= N` now. Now we get the answer `i - 2` because it is the only number that satisfy the above requirement.

#### Why is `dp[i - 1] > N`?

Because of how i++ works, `dp[i++] <= N` is actually `dp[i] <= N; i++;` therefore there will be an extra increment in the end. Therefore `dp[i - 1] > N` must be satisfied in the end.

#### Why is `dp[i - 2] <= N`?

Because in the loop before, we executed the last loop because `dp[i++] <= N` evaluated to true when `i` is the final `i` minus 2, thus continuing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are only three ways of understanding this problem (or maybe four if we want to be very creative).

If loser of any match can no longer compete, then above explanation solver the problem and we have to solve recursion for Fibonacci numbers.

In the second way of understanding the statement the player who loses a game can still compete with other contestants. Here we will have a trivial solution, that the winner will be able to win *i* matches if there are *i+1* players at the beginning of the tournament. It is easy to show using recursion that this is true for two players and each next player will win with all previous players.

The third approach comes to my mind from the chess world where in the single round of the tournament all, or all but one player have to play, but in this case I believe there could be some cases where due to problem constraints it would be impossible to create such matching for some round.

And last (very stretched) way is to think that players can play with each other arbitrary number of times. In such case two players can reach any number of wins if they only win every other game.

The last, quoted sentence in Your question also seems to make sense. If we look at *i* after the process, due to implementation, it will be one greater than the first number greater than the answer, so we should return *i-2*.

Answer (score 0):

First we want to compute function `F`,  this function takes the number of players as input and its output is the maximum number of games the winner can plays given the requirements of the problem. now I claim `F` is equivalent with the function `P`, and function `P` takes the number of games that the winner played and its output is the minimum number of players that are required to create that many games. i.e.

```
P(#games) = minimum number of players
F(#players) = maximum number of games
```

you can consider `P` like this: maximum number of games that `n` players can create for winner. from now we work with `P`

now consider `James` is the winner and his `#games` is `n`. before the last game `James` played with the `Bob` according to the requirements of the problem the number of games for `James` and `Bob` must be one of the following:

```
 #games James played = n-1 and #games Bob played=n-1 (state 1)
 #games James played = n-1 and #games Bob played=n-2 (state 2)


            James(#games = n) 
        /                    \
       /                      \
  James(#games = n - 1)  vs   Bob(#games = n - 2) or (#games = n - 1)
```

some facts until now

- we want to compute `P(n)` = minimum number of players can create `n` games or [read it like maximum number of games that those players can create for winner.]
- The players in left and right sub trees are disjoint you can easily verify there is not a player who exist in both sub trees.
- `P(n) = P(n-1) + p(n-2)` or `P(n) = 2P(n-1)` we can verify that `2P(n-1) >= P(n-1) + p(n-2)` and we want minimum number of players so we consider  `P(n) = P(n-1) + p(n-2)`

for implementation part, I have `N` players what is the maximum number of games that the winner can play or what is the minimum number of players that can create `M` wins? it is actually `P` function

```
M = 0 --> 1  players needed 
M = 1 --> 2  players needed 
M = 2 --> 3  players needed
M = 3 --> 5  players needed (5 players can create at most 3 games for the winner)

.....
```

when the computed players exceeds the `N`(number of available players) we should return previous index. for example if the number of players is 4 when we compute the number of players for `M=3` it is 5 and `5 > 4` so we must return `2`

Answer (score 0):

To be very simple, if you want a winner that is winning N matches, you need a winner that is winning N - 1 matches and a winner that is winning N - 2 matches, as the number of wins from two competitors needs to be smaller or equal than 1.

So the recurrence relation is simply `dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]`.